# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT IOS Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ProReaderAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This happen after i try to some of the view in IOS Simulator

[image: Crash log]

Comment: there is nothing what can be said about the error in your question (except this error happens due to memory management). Try to set Exception Breakpoint: the last but one tab on the left and tap on "plus" button in the left down corner. Then paste your code which caused the exception

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769245/terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception Are your outlets correctly connected to UI elements?

Comment: still, very little information to detect error. Describe the problem more specifically, try to understand which code crashes the app, google error message. No one needs to do your work for you

Comment: I did google it for 3 hours now. nothing come up everything is correctly connected. and there is no error. the error comes up when i press a button. I when through all the code linked to that button also, everything is fine until i press + sign in IOS Simulator . Here is a link to screentshot of 0_pthread_kill http://postimg.org/image/tvwtjv34n/

Comment: You might want to read [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1), which talks about next steps for diagnosing the crash. But there's not enough here to diagnose the problem. But I second the idea of adding an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) as you can sometimes quickly identify the offending line of code that way.

Comment: @Rob Thank you so much while you were commenting i actually was reading that article and it help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem! 
It seems that you have linked, lets say a button/label/imageView etc. and you don't use it or they are duplicates: this ERROR will occur. 
So, go to your Connection inspector:

- open your storyboard
- check all your connections and see/check, if you have any duplicates and remove them.

This should get rid of your problem :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In order to find what's wrong.

First, set the Exception Breakpoint, switch to the **Breakpoint Navigator**:

[image: Breakpoint Navigator]

Second, at the bottom is a small + button. Click this and select **Add Exception Breakpoint**:

[image: Add Exception Breakpoint]

[More detail can be found HERE.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy boo I often get this same as you and usually it's because I set an object up and linked it with an IBAction then I delete it.

I hope that helps you <3 best of luck of friend

NEVER GIVE UP!!

Answer (score 0):

For any others still having issues with this. I deleted my View controller connections via the  connections inspector and then relinked them back to my IB Outlet properties and it solved my problem.

Hope that made sense!