# Display the slope view controller in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

An issue I have in XCode 5 seems to be resolved by the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769245/terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception).  However, that question has you take certain actions in a window entitled "Slope View Controller".  Can anyone point me to the place in XCode 5's UI where I can access this window?  I suspect that screen shot might be an older version and I need to be looking at something else, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SlopeViewController` is nothing just name of viewController. You can acess that window by **right clicking on `view controller`(Yellow square on left side of image) in storyboard**

[image]

**As you see in my picture it is showing `Master View Controller` by right clicking on yellow `Master View Controller`**

Comment: Do you need to have a .storyboard file for that to appear? The project I'm working on doesn't have one, and I don't see that anywhere on the screen.

Comment: If you have `xib` than you can see this window also.Right click on it