# IOS: How to open View Controller settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my program I am getting an NSException. I researched and found a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769245/terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception) topic. However, I cannot find how I should open the View Controller settings shown in the picture of the accepted answer. My Xcode version is 6.1.1. Any directions?

Comment: try to open by right clicking on file's owner

Comment: Open the storyboard, click on the view controller object, choose the File Inspector tab, check on the connection Inspector. Or Just right click on the view controller object in your storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the connection menu for the view controller.  To open it, **control-click** or **right-click** on the view controller:

[image: view controller connections in work area]

You can also control-click or right-click on the view controller in the document outline:

[image: view controller connections in document outline]

You can also use the Connections Inspector, which appears in the right side of the Xcode window:

[image: connections inspector]