# linker command failed with exit code 1 please help me to fix this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

`ld: '/Users/ompatel/Downloads/Answer My Question 2/RevMobAds.framework/RevMobAds(RevMobCDataScanner.o)'` does not contain `bitcode`. You must rebuild it with `bitcode` enabled `(Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)`, obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture `armv7`
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Set "bitcode- No "  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32466484/4970453      Check This link @om

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: how to fix this bug                                                                                               libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Have you checked this Answer  ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389647/4970453

Comment: Just remove yellow errors   ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/17770531/4970453

Comment: My app is build in sprite builder so i need a answer about sprite builder

Comment: I don't have any idea about sprite builder